# Inconsistent behaviour creating symbolic links with relative and force flag

Tags: ln

I have an issue with creating symbolic links with `ln`, with the relative and the force flag set.

The scenario is as follows:

```
$ tree
.
├── folder1
│   └── file
└── folder2
```

I create the link:

```
$ ln -sfr folder1/file folder2
$ tree
.
├── folder1
│   └── file
└── folder2
    └── file -> ../folder1/file
```

This is as I want it. But when I re-execute the command, I don't understand why the link is now pointing to itself:

```
$ ln -sfr folder1/file folder2
$ tree
.
├── folder1
│   └── file
└── folder2
    └── file -> file
```

Executing the command a third time corrects the error:

```
$ ln -sfr folder1/file folder2
$ tree
.
├── folder1
│   └── file
└── folder2
    └── file -> ../folder1/file
```

Re-executing the command multiple times toggles between two states. I really wonder why this is. According to the manual this should be no issue.

The `ln` version used (as shipped with Ubuntu 14.10):

```
$ ln --version
ln (GNU coreutils) 8.21
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug and appears in the coreutils from version 8.16 to 8.21. It was fixed in 8.22. From the release notes of version 8.22:

> ln --relative now updates existing symlinks correctly.  Previously it based
>    the relative link on the dereferenced path of an existing link.
>    [This bug was introduced when --relative was added in coreutils-8.16.]

https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7815